# British comedy about stupid aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a rather funny movie I saw perhaps a decade or more ago on British TV - I only recall a few details:

- You follow a small group - one woman, two men - on a sort of interstellar heavy goods vehicle; they are really not very sophisticated.
- They crash-land on the M25 motorway (around London) and take out several bridges.
- It is observed by a couple of police officers in a traffic patrol, who report the incident much like they would report an ordinary traffic accident.

I haven't been able to think of the right combination of words to find it - any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

[Morons from Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morons_from_Outer_Space)? Based on the wikipedia summary a number of elements fit - two men, one woman (in the main party), lists two traffic policemen in the cast list.

Youtube trailer

Comment: Beat me by a hair

Comment: This looks like great fun - but I don't think this is the one. Thanks a lot, though!

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Odd since it seems to satisfy at least 2 of your your remembered details, 3 crew and M25 crash. Unlikely that these would be duplicated in another movie (but not impossible I guess)

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, it is very similar, but I don't recall Griff Rhys Jones and Mel Smith being in it. I'll have to watch it in full to be sure.